# Auto Increment a Variable

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to get the step number to increase with each step that is pulled from the database.  Here is my code:

```
//get the project steps 
$ID=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['id']);         
      $projSteps="SELECT project_steps.projectStepDesc,project_steps.projectID FROM project_steps WHERE project_steps.projectID=$ID";  
    $results1 = mysqli_query($con,$projSteps);  
    if (!$results1) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}   
       if (mysqli_num_rows($results1) > 0){
        echo '<h2>Project Steps:</h2>';           

 while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results1))
    {
      $a=1;
      echo "Step ". $a++ ."<br />";
      $psteps=$rows['projectStepDesc'];
      echo '<div id="steps">';
      echo "$psteps";
      echo '</div>';
      }}//end project steps
```

This just outputs Step 1 on each step.  I am trying to get it to say Step 1, Step 2, Step 3 ect.  How can i do this?

Comment: Initialize `$a = 1` _before_ the start of the `while` loop. That is critical, or it is reset to 1 on each iteration.

Comment: put **$a=1;** **outside** while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the counter inside the while loop. This won't work as, `$a = 1;` is called each time you loop through and do something. Change:

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results1))
    {
      $a=1;
```

To:

```
$a=1;
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results1))
    {
```

Comment: This worked great...dont know how i missed that...i will vote for this answer.  can you upvote my question?

Comment: Sure. It's an easy thing to miss, but learn from your mistakes and you'll be fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `$a = 1` within your loop each time. Put it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have put $a=1 outside the while ,other wise when the loops runs value of a gets changes to 1 every time.

```
    $ID=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['id']);         
  $projSteps="SELECT project_steps.projectStepDesc,project_steps.projectID FROM         project_steps WHERE project_steps.projectID=$ID";  
$results1 = mysqli_query($con,$projSteps);  
if (!$results1) {
      printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
     exit();
   }   
   if (mysqli_num_rows($results1) > 0){
    echo '<h2>Project Steps:</h2>';           
     $a=1;
       while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results1))
    {

  echo "Step ". $a++ ."<br />";
  $psteps=$rows['projectStepDesc'];
  echo '<div id="steps">';
  echo "$psteps";
  echo '</div>';
  }}//end project steps
```